# How to send file to Sails from AngularJS without using custom directives?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, sails.js

So I need to upload an image to the server. Right now it works only with a POST request made via HTML. But I need to send other data and do other stuff before uploading it, so I'd like to send the request inside an Angular controller, using `$http.post(...)`. I've seen some really complex solutions using custom directives, but I'd like to know if there's anyway to do something straight forward like:

```
$scope.uploadPhoto = function(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("uploadFile", $scope.file);
    $http.post('file/upload', fd);
}
```

Working code:

HTML:

```
<form id="uploadForm"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  action="/file/upload"
  method="post">
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Sails Controller:

```
upload: function  (req, res) {
    var uploadFile = req.file('uploadFile');

    uploadFile.upload(
        { dirname: '../../assets/images',
            saveAs: function(file, cb) {
                cb(null, file.filename);
            }
        }, function onUploadComplete (err, files) {             
            if (err) return res.serverError(err);                                   
            res.json({status:200,file:files});
    });
}
```